# text-align:center; doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have been messing around with the layout of my website and my  `text-align : center;` stopped working
that happened after i set all my divs position to relative to make the parent div change size when I add components to it with javascript.

Here are both of my CSS files:

You can see the new one in the JSfiddle link below.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2WvrV/

I also provide the code for the old website (which aligns the text properly) :

http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlerOnDaRoof/fQpjX/

the old HTML is very similar to the new version i just added the style="float:left;" in one of the divs

Comment: ur margin spelling is wrong in many places... check it...

Comment: thanks a lot! I fixed the margin spelling and it works now. Just need to fix the align-center now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out. All i needed to do is to add 
`clear:left;` to my `loginBttn` div
after that everything worked fine

thanks for trying to help everybody

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: your text isn't centered because the elements are floated, and floated elements "shrink" to the content, even if it's a block level element.

Can you explain more what this means?

> I had to set all my position to relative to make the parent div change
>   size when I add components to it with javascript

Comment: I have 2 display:none; divs inside the main div. when i make them display:inline; with javascript i need the box to increase its length. Now if the div gets shrinked to the size of the content then when i take out the width and height and text-align attributes it should automatically center the text. but that doesnt happen the content is still of center

Answer (score 8):

Anywhere you have `float:left;` in your CSS, add `width: 100%;` after it. Floating will kill your desired center alignment.

Also, add `text-align: center;` to `#login`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another case why Text-align: center, didn't work.

You are using **display:flex** property in above Div, so you need to remove that and then try it will work.

Comment: This certainly was my problem too but I needed both `display: flex;` _and_ `text-align center;`.
The workaround I found was to use `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` instead of `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add `width: 100%;` in your CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at your code, I saw that all the elements needed to be properly spaced as in:

```css
element{
    text-align: center;
};
```

where as you had:

```css
element{
    text-align:center;
};
```

Also, you have some spelling errors:

```css
element{
    magin-left: 9px;
};
```

Where it should be:

```css
element{
    margin-left: 9px;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

try this. i guess it might help you

```
text-align:justify;
```