# Can't center <li> inside <ul>

Tags: html, css, menu, menuitem, centering

I'm trying it for a long time. I found many solutions, but none of them worked. I need to center the li inside ul (menu div and ul are the right size I need).

CSS:

```
div.menu {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  margin: 0px;
}
li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 128px;
  height: 77px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
      <a href="#" class="menu"><li>Item 1</li></a>
      <a href="#" class="menu"><li>Item 2</li></a>
   </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT: I need to center **horizontaly** all of the LIs.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhW3M.png)

Comment: What needs to be centered, and does it need to be vertically or horizontally centered. Tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The first child of `<ul>` can only be a `<li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are designing a menu you need this markup:

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu">Item 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and this CSS to align the items:

```
div.menu {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  margin: 0px;
  background:lightcyan; //for visualization only
}

.menu ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu ul li {
  display:inline-flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 128px;
  height: 77px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background:lightblue; //for visualization only
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.menu ul li a {
  align-self:center;
}
```

Check the JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r2gnkknv/

You will end with this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understand you... try that one:

CSS:

```
div.menu {
    margin: 0 10%;
    width: 128px; /* it's the root case */
}
ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center de <li> you have to give a width to the <ul> element,if you want to center the text inside de <li> then you should set a text-align:center in your <li> styles

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough to center the text. Give the div an ID and center that. Be careful though as applying float will actually have the negative effect - [text-align:center; doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408072/text-aligncenter-doesnt-work)

```
#centerText
{
text-align: center;
}

<div class="menu" id="centerText">
    <ul>
       <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give a width to your Unordered List element. Using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you can use justify-content to center the list items or to space them around the ul. You can't center an element if its floating in your case the li elements. Remove the float and add display: inline-block and it should work as well.

```css
*{margin: 0;}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.menu a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu">Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="menu">Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="menu">Item 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="menu">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the li class try removing the float: left and replace it with display: inline-block;. I think that will do what you're trying to accomplish. If not please give us more details.

**CSS**

```
div.menu {
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    margin: 0px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 128px;
    height: 77px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdOaLd

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that saved my day on this issue:

```
.tab ul{list-style-type: none;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;text-align: center;}
.tab li{display: inline-block;padding: 2px;float: none !important;}
```